# error when compiling the sqlite documentation code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite

I copied this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
    printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
sqlite3 *db;
char *zErrMsg = 0;
int rc;
char *sql;

/* Open database */
rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

if (rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return(0);
}
else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
}

/* Create SQL statement */
sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY("  \
    "ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
    "NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL," \
    "AGE            INT     NOT NULL," \
    "ADDRESS        CHAR(50)," \
    "SALARY         REAL );";

/* Execute SQL statement */
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}
else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");
}
sqlite3_close(db);
return 0;
}
```

from official documentation sqlite here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm
and I got error like this:

```
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'const char [164]' to 'char *'
```

I'm using visual studio 2017 and compile file .cpp. I guess something can be wrong with connection between .c and .cpp files, because sqlite is written in .c

Comment: Where is the error triggered? There is no `const char[164]` in this code.

Comment: What line of your code is the error on? If it's not your code, please show the code where the error is. Your code is more C than C++, you might consider just compiling it as such.

Comment: yes, of course, I put here wrong code, sorry for that. I edited post, error is when I initialize variable 'sql'

Comment: Do you know what makes `char *` different from `const char *`?

Comment: Both are pointers, but const char* points to a location that can not be changed, but the value of this location can be changed

Comment: You should declare sql as const char * since VS 2015 (and  +) check the assignment between const char * to char *.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: at the line `sql = "..."`, and `sql` is declared as `char *`.

Comment: It works. I do not know if I understand correctly, but if the function argument is const char * then I can not send char *?

Comment: @tunglt the code was heavily edited since my comment :p

Comment: Tutorialspoint is not "official" anything for sqlite, and, honestly, a lot of of the code I've seen from it is *horrible*. Case in point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are using old C-style variable declaration (all at the beginning) in C++ with the wrong types.

Use this instead:

```
const char* sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY("  \
    "ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
    "NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL," \
    "AGE            INT     NOT NULL," \
    "ADDRESS        CHAR(50)," \
    "SALARY         REAL );";
```

Literal char* are const in C++11.